# Fetching Json from api error Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dio

Hello i have one question i was fetching categories from api which works fine in postman but on flutter i didn't use model class just using dio i need to fetch this json api as an array for top bar vertical scroll of categories.

here is my postman response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Electronics",
            "color": "#ff8000"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "SpareParts",
            "color": "#00ff40"
        },
        
    ]
}
```

and in flutter i used

```
getCatagories() async {
    var tokens;

    var dioo = Dio();
    dioo.interceptors
        .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
      var customHeaders = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      };
      options.headers.addAll(customHeaders);
      return options;
    }));

    var response = await dioo.get("https://www.mywebiste.com/api/cat");
    if(response.data.isEmpty||response.data==null)
    {
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return response.data;


  }
```

to fetch these catagories
i have used

```
List categories = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
   getCatagories().then((data) {
      setState(() {
         categories = data;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }


  // by default first item will be selected


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: kDefaultPadding / 2),
      height: 30,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "This is Center Short Toast"+selectedIndex.toString(),
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0
            );
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: kDefaultPadding,
              // At end item it add extra 20 right  padding
              right: index == categories.length - 1 ? kDefaultPadding : 0,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: index == selectedIndex
                  ? Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4)
                  : Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
            ),
            child: Text(
              categories[index],
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

so when i run these app categories will not appear for scrollbar and error is Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the data from request as Map and assigning it to List.
you should make categories as Map:

```
Map categories;
```

Note: don't give it generics.

after that you will have some problems in the code below while looping in the categories.
That's another question. :)